# How to use an anchor tag to submit when using Html.BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can one use an anchor tag to submit when using `Html.BeginForm`? The `BeginForm` method does not have a way of giving the form name it seems, so that I could do this

```
<a href="JAVASCRIPT:Form1.submit()">Next</a>
```

This fails because no `Form1` exists.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using jQuery use

```
<a href="javascript:$('form').submit();">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how you add a "name" attribute using the htmlAttributes object

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "MyFormName" }))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you've only got one form on the page the following code should work:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('form').item(0).submit()">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative jQuery solution using `onclick` and `.closest('form')`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit(); return false;">My link</a>
```